# PHP & MySQL: Storing more than 100 settings in an integer using bitwise operators?

Tags: php, mysql, bitwise-operators

I would like to store some options in MySQL as a sigle integer as it's described in [C & PHP: Storing settings in an integer using bitwise operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773914/c-php-storing-settings-in-an-integer-using-bitwise-operators). However I have more than 100 options to store (2^124 int?) so I'm wondering if there is a better way to store such a big number (64-base number as a VARCHAR?) and a way of checking chosen settings.

For your interest - I try to update some simple Reagents Databese I've made for my work on university, and I like to add GHS Statements to my records.

Maybe I'll simply divide the list into smaller chunks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not gonna say "don't do that", but i'll say it will be a nightmare to maintain. I've used these "monsters" before.

Comment: Is there any reason why a simple 100 character field won't work?  After all these days storage is cheaper than your sanity!

Comment: Even [the dedicated data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html) falls short but, well, I guess you can always have two columns ;-)

Comment: This is really a bad call. Make another table with options, and a "join table" to relate the records to these options. Bitfields are a total nightmare to work with outside of a strictly C context, Alex Tartan isn't wrong.

Comment: Thank You all, I think I will choose a char array ;)