# What do the '&=' and '=&' operators do?

Tags: php, variables, operators

Finding the answer to this is turning out to be much more difficult than I would have thought. Since I don't have a clue what you'd call this, it's hard to run a Google search since it will ignore those characters.

I tried browsing the [PHP Assignment Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) page, and even the other operators pages, and found nothing that told me exactly what they do. I don't just want to guess based on the single function I have that uses it. So what exactly do the '&=' and '=&' operators do?

All I know is it sets a variable, which would be the '=' part, so I really need to know what the '&' part is doing.

Please don't say the obvious; I need someone to explain exactly what they do. I know one of them is 'bitwise', but that doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: They are completely different operators as the answers reflect.

Comment: I had the same problem trying to look this up myself. The documentation could be better organized, but you basically have to look on the _Bitwise Operator_ page and the _What References Do_ page. Also, I think assigning by reference is usually written `$a = &$b`, but I guess the space between the `=` and `&` are optional.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: I prefer using `$a = &$b`. It's much clearer, because the `&` does not belong to the equal sign, but the variable actually. It's similar to `a --> 0` "goes to" operator, which in reality is `a-- > 0`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/985454
So much to the confusement.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`=&` [assigns by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

```
$a = 1;
$b =& $a;
$a++;
echo $b; // 2
```

From PHP Manual on References:

> References in PHP are a means to access the same variable content by different names.

---

`&=` is a [bitwise AND](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) assignment

```
$a = 1;
$a &= 1; // is the same as
$a = $a & 1;
echo $a; // 1
```

From [Wikipedia on Bitwise AND:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

> A bitwise AND takes two binary representations of equal length and performs the logical AND operation on each pair of corresponding bits. In each pair, the result is 1 if the first bit is 1 AND the second bit is 1. Otherwise, the result is 0. For example:

```
    0101
AND 0011
  = 0001
```

---

**EDIT:** For a practical example on bitwise operations, see my answer to [Bitwise Operations in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131758/bitwise-operations-in-php/2131828#2131828)

Comment: I prefer using `$a = &$b`. It's much clearer, because the `&` does not belong to the equal sign, but the variable actually. It's similar to `a --> 0` "goes to" operator, which in reality is `a-- > 0`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/985454

Comment: @Gordon Food for though = https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914758/2943403

Answer (score 10):

`=&` is [assigning by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign).

It assigns a variable not by value but by reference.

Example:

```
$a = 'foo';
$b =& $a;

$b = 'bar';

echo $a;
```

prints `bar` because `$b` has a reference to `$a` and therefore changing `$b` also changes the value of `$a`.

---

`&=` is [bitwise `AND`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Example:

```
$a = 4 // binary representation: 100
$b = 1 // binary representation: 001
```

Then `$a &= $b` is just short for `$a = $a & $b` and means: Take every bit and perform the [`AND` operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_AND#AND), that is:

```
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
0 & 0 = 0
```

Therefore

```
     1 0 0 
AND  0 0 1
     -----
     0 0 0

=> $a = 0 // bit representation 0 ;)
```

Comment: Food for thought: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914758/2943403

Answer (score 2):

```
&=
```

is the bitwise "AND" assignment operator. It performs an "AND" on the variable and stores the result. (more information is in *[Bitwise Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)* and more general information is in *[Bitwise Operations in C](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1563.asp)* ).

The

```
=&
```

operator is an assignment by reference, which makes the variable point not to the value of the other variable or constant, but rather to that memory location (more information is in *[What References Are](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php)*).

Comment: `=&` is not a combined operator.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914758/2943403 and consider adjusting your answer

Answer (score 1):

'&=' and '=&' are very different operators.

'&=' is a bitwise assignment operator:

```
$var = false;
$var &= foo(); // will call foo()
$var = false & foo(); // will call foo()
$var = $var && foo(); // will not call foo()
```

'=&' returns a reference:

```
$a = $b; //$a points to $b
$a =& $b; //$a does NOT point to $b... both point to the same thing.
```

Comment: Please read this hairsplitting post and consider tweaking your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914758/2943403

Answer (score 0):

"=&" means input a value, that the content will adapt with the previous  variable
[the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxdea.png)

the output is =
satu
satu

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).